# Nested ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to loop on li element but somehow it is not showing li elements.

Here is my data which I am looping.

```
{    "30":{
      "data":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "report_name":"Jimit Advizer Report",
            "is_generated":0,
            "shopify_account_id":30,
            "total_sales":null,
            "created_at":"2016-01-15 06:11:48",
            "updated_at":"2016-01-15 06:11:48",
            "shop_title":"Jimit's Store"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "report_name":"Jimit Advizer Collection Report",
            "is_generated":0,
            "shopify_account_id":30,
            "total_sales":null,
            "created_at":"2016-01-15 06:13:32",
            "updated_at":"2016-01-15 06:13:32",
            "shop_title":"Jimit's Store"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "report_name":"Matt Advizer Report",
            "is_generated":0,
            "shopify_account_id":30,
            "total_sales":null,
            "created_at":"2016-01-15 12:08:22",
            "updated_at":"2016-01-15 12:08:22",
            "shop_title":"Jimit's Store"
         }
      ]    
    }
}
```

**Controller**

vm.reports = reports.data;

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-header-item clearfix" ng-repeat="(report_id, reports) in vm.reports track by $index">
                        <h4>Woof Product Shopify Store</h4>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="r in reports.data track by $index">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 p-0">
                            <h5>Necklace Revenue Advizer<br/><small>1/15/16 - currently generating</small></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 m-t-5">
                            $17,357 <br/> <b>Total Sales</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-right m-t-5">
                            <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect m-r-5">View</button>
                            <button class="btn bgm-amber btn-default waves-effect m-r-5">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-default waves-effect m-r-5" >Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Why I am not able to see other "li"?

Comment: Your second li is not __in__ the first one and therefore doesn't know anything about `reports`.

Comment: So, I guess `vm.reports` is the `data` **array** in your JSON. But you're iterating it as if it was an object, having keys.

Comment: shouldn't it be `<li class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="r in reports['30'].data track by $index">`, I think your `reports` object is the one you shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` instance exits on it's inside closing node.

After that it has no existence.

This reports

```
<li class="list-header-item clearfix" ng-repeat="(report_id, reports) in vm.reports track by $index">
    <h4>Woof Product Shopify Store</h4>
</li>
```

has no effect on

```
<li class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="r in reports.data track by $index">
```

as 2nd code is outside of it's boundary

Try like this

```
<li class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="r in vm.reports['30']['data'] track by $index">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/kLju9krc/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: That's correct but how can I iterate dynamically here? here "30" is dynamic value I want to iterate dynamically.

Comment: Just wrap your li with span : check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/kLju9krc/3/ @Jimit